# Django admin exclude subclass

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a couple of models that look along the lines of:

```
class Page(SomeBaseClass):
    # random fields


class Link(Page):
    # some other fields
```

And in my `admin.py` I've registered these classes:

```
admin.site.register(Page) # shows both Pages and Links
admin.site.register(Link) # shows only Links
```

At this point the "Pages" tab in the Admin shows both `Page` and `Link` and the "Links" tab shows only `Link`. Is it possible to exclude the `Link` model from the "Pages" tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could override [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) for the model admin, and use [`isnull`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) to filter objects without a child.

```
class PageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(PageAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(link__isnull=True)

admin.site.register(Page, PageAdmin)
```

Comment: Where does the `MyModelAdmin` come from? Is it supposed to be `PageAdmin`?

Comment: Yes, it's meant to be `PageAdmin`

Comment: It works now, however I'm still getting both links and pages in the list. Maybe the `link__isnull` isn't matching anything?

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood what you're trying to do. With the code above, if I go to `/admin/myapp/page/`, then any pages with a related link are not shown.

Comment: True, its another module that I'm using that's messing with it. When I use the default Django admin it works fine. Thank you for the help.